# PHP Telegram Button Array will not be issued

Tags: php, telegram

I've created a Button-Array and it looks like this (Output with `print_r`):

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [text] => 1. Bayer Leverkusen - 1. FC KÃ¶ln
                    [callback_data] => 64136
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [text] => 2. 1. FSV Mainz 05 - FC Schalke 04
                    [callback_data] => 64142
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [text] => 3. FC Augsburg - 1. FC Union Berlin
                    [callback_data] => 64135
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [text] => 4. Borussia MÃ¶nchengladbach - VfL Bochum
                    [callback_data] => 64138
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [text] => 5. SC Freiburg - RB Leipzig â
                    [callback_data] => 64139
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [text] => 6. Hertha BSC - VfB Stuttgart
                    [callback_data] => 64140
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [text] => 7. TSG 1899 Hoffenheim - Eintracht Frankfurt
                    [callback_data] => 64141
                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [text] => 8. Werder Bremen - FC Bayern
                    [callback_data] => 64143
                )

        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [text] => 9. Borussia Dortmund - VfL Wolfsburg
                    [callback_data] => 64137
                )

        )

    [9] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

I use the following code to create this array:

```php
$table = 'prefix_tippspiel_teams';
$uid = 104;
$green_checkmark = "\xE2\x9C\x85";

$min_date = ''; $max_date = ''; $counter = 0; $kb = array(); $lines = array(); $matchlist = array();
$abf_matches = db_query("SELECT sp.match_id, sp.datum, sp.heim_id, sp.gast_id, sp.tore_heim, sp.tore_gast, sp.finished,
                            t1.team_id as heim_id, t1.team_name as heim_team, t1.team_icon as heim_icon, t2.team_id as gast_id, t2.team_name as gast_team, t2.team_icon as gast_icon
                        FROM prefix_tippspiel_spiele as sp
                            LEFT JOIN $table as t1 ON sp.heim_id = t1.team_id
                            LEFT JOIN $table as t2 ON sp.gast_id = t2.team_id
                        WHERE competition = 'liga' AND sp.spieltag = 31 ORDER BY sp.datum ASC");

while($row = db_fetch_assoc($abf_matches)) {
    if ($row['finished'] == 1) {
        continue;
    }

    if ($counter == 0 && $min_date == '') {
        $min_date = $row['datum'];
    }
    $max_date = $row['datum'];

    $data = http_build_query([
        'text' => utf8_encode("Wähle ein Spiel des ".$matchday.". Spieltages (" . date('d.m.y', $min_date) . " - " . date('d.m.y', $max_date) . ")"),
        'chat_id' => $update['message']['from']['id']
    ]);

    $mid = $row['match_id'];
    $tipp_done = '';
    if (0 < db_result(db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM prefix_tippspiel_tipps WHERE mid = " . $mid . " AND uid = " . $uid . " AND (tore_heim IS NOT NULL AND tore_gast IS NOT NULL)"))) {
        $tipp_done = " "."$green_checkmark";
    }
    $heim_team = $row['heim_team'];
    $gast_team = $row['gast_team'];

    # hier statt 60 die aus den settings tippsperre...tipplock_seconds
    if (($row['datum'] - $tipplock_seconds) > $now) {
        $counter++;

        // Create keyboard
        array_push($lines, array("text" => utf8_encode($counter.". ".$heim_team." - ".$gast_team).$tipp_done, "callback_data" => $mid));
        $rows++;
        if ($rows == 1) {
            array_push($kb, $lines);
            $lines = array();
            $rows = 0;
        }

        # Matchlist-Array für spätere Abfrage füllen
        $matchlist[] = $counter.". ".$heim_team." - ".$gast_team;
    }
}
array_push($kb, $lines);
$keyboard = json_encode(array("keyboard" => $kb, "one_time_keyboard" => true, "resize_keyboard" => true));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($kb);
echo '</pre>';
```

I left out some things in the code.
On the first `array_push`, when I replace `$heim_team` with `$gast_team`, I at least get the buttons.

I suspect there is a problem with the `$home_team` variable, but the output via `print_r` shows that the home teams are set correctly.

Could someone please tell me where I'm wrong? Thanks very much!

Comment: Please provide both teams, so we have a minimal reproducible example. Also put them as code or at least export with `var_export()`.

Comment: Look here for the code I used to create the array: [link](https://codeshare.io/Pd9J0E)

Comment: Please edit your question and do not link external resources.

Comment: I edited the first post, sorry for mistake.

Comment: Please read the first comment again. print_r output is useless for reproduction.